# How to load respective tableviewcontrollers in the detailview of splitview when user selects a particular row in the master tableviwcontroller?

Tags: ios

I have an application developed for iPhone, now I am trying to make changes in the application so that it supports for iPad too,for that I am using splitviewcontroller. I am facing problem to load data in the tableview on detailview while selecting a row in the master view of splitview. each row of masterview directs to data that to be loaded in detailview. any help is helpful...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your code where you are facing issue?

Comment: what is issue you are facing please post your code here